# setting 4k resolution with xrandr fails with badmatch error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, xrandr

I have a 4k monitor and try to set my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to use it. Since there is no 3840x2160 option available in system settings and NVIDIA X Server Settings - the only way to do that is using xrandr tool.
So I type:

```
gtf 3840 2160 60

# 3840x2160 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 134.10 kHz; pclk: 712.34 MHz
  Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.34  3840 4152 4576 5312  2160 2161 2164 2235  -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --newmode test87 712.34  3840 4152 4576 5312  2160 2161 2164 2235  -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 test87

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

It seems like a common error, but other solution suggest modifying the /etc/X11/xorg.conf (that I don't have, I tried to create one and reboot but it does not help). Some others solutiond suggest using brackets around mode names - it does not help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not entirely mistaken 4k@60Hz is simply beyond the bandwidth capabilities of HDMI-1.4; you either need to connect via DisplayPort or use a lower refresh rate; 30Hz would be a safe bet.

#### Update

Given the EDID data dump everything looks fine so far. The `xorg.conf` entries that correspond to your display would be these (generated by parse-edid, which would be equivalent to what the X.org server does).

```
    # EDID version 1 revision 3
Section "Monitor"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    Identifier "ASUS PB287Q"
    VendorName "ACI"
    ModelName "ASUS PB287Q"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
    HorizSync 24-160
    VertRefresh 30-80
    # Max dot clock (video bandwidth) 300 MHz
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    # DPMS capabilities: Active off:yes  Suspend:no  Standby:no

    Mode    "3840x2160" # vfreq 30.000Hz, hfreq 67.500kHz
        DotClock    297.000000
        HTimings    3840 4016 4104 4400
        VTimings    2160 2168 2178 2250
        Flags   "-HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
    Mode    "1920x1080" # vfreq 60.000Hz, hfreq 67.500kHz
        DotClock    148.500000
        HTimings    1920 2008 2052 2200
        VTimings    1080 1084 1089 1125
        Flags   "+HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
EndSection
```

Note the UHD resolution mode.

Hadn't you mentioned that the NVidia X Server Settings tool can be used I'd have suspected a broken driver installation. Anyway I strongly you double check, that the drivers are properly installed and nothing is interfering with them.

Comment: That is not correct, the same mistake occurs attempting to set it any resolution on any frequency

Comment: @DraifKroneg: Well, I just looked into the HDMI-1.4 spec (I've got a copy) and yes, UHD@60Hz is clearly beyond its limits. Regarding this failing for other modes and frequencies you could try using `cvt` instead of `gtf`.

Comment: Why do you think I am using HDMI-1.4?  nothing says it anywhere, does it?

Comment: cvt did not work, it produces different output with hsync ans vsync lower cased, apart from that - no difference

Comment: @DraifKroneg: Could you please extract the EDID information of your monitor and post it into your question? You can dump the EDID info with `xrandr --verbose` – maybe the X server is seeing something in the EDID that may make it prevent switching to that mode.

Comment: @DraifKroneg: You could also install the `read-edid` package and run `sudo get-edid | parse-edid`

Comment: sudo get-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.1. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface

 Performing real mode VBE call
 Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
 Function supported
 Call successful

 VBE version 300
 VBE string at 0x11100 "NVIDIA"

Comment: VBE/DDC service about to be called
 Report DDC capabilities

 Performing real mode VBE call
 Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
 Function supported
 Call successful

 Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 transfers
 Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC2 transfers
 0 seconds per 128 byte EDID block transfer
 Screen is not blanked during DDC transfer

Comment: Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
 Read EDID

 Performing real mode VBE call
 Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
 Function supported
 Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
I'm sorry nothing was successful. Maybe try some other arguments
if you played with them, or send an email to Matthew Kern <pyrophobicman@gmail.com>

Comment: xrandr --verbose                            EDID: 
  some very long number
 SignalFormat: TMDS 
  supported: TMDS
 ConnectorType: HDMI 
 ConnectorNumber: 3 
 _ConnectorLocation: 3 
  1920x1080 (0x280)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz

Comment: @DraifKroneg: Well, I'd like to see that very long number. It's a hexdump of your monitor's EDID information block. In late 2013 I designed this thing: https://events.ccc.de/congress/2013/wiki/Projects:VGA_EDID_Injector – so I'd like to look into that data to see what's going on.

Comment: EDID: 
  00ffffffffffff000469a328045b0200
  1e180103803e22783a1cb5a3574fa027
  0d5054bfef00d1c0814081809500b300
  714f81c0010104740030f2705a80b058
  8a006d552100001a023a801871382d40
  582c45006d552100001e000000fd001e
  5018a01e000a202020202020000000fc
  0041535553205042323837510a20018a
  02032cf1510102031112130414050e0f
  1d1e1f90202223091707830100006d03
  0c002000003c200060010203565e00a0
  a0a02950302035006d552100001ee268
  00a0a0402e60302036006d552100001a
  011d00bc52d01e20b82855406d552100
  001e8c0ad090204031200c4055006d55
  2100001800000000000000000000005e

Answer (score 0):

You can't use xrandr with the nVidia proprietary driver. Get back to the driver included in Ubuntu and try again.

Moreover, you can not always depend on cvt and gtf. You may have to get the working numbers by finding your device EDID and reading it by parse-edid.

These two solved my similar issue.